# Как передавать члены структуры, а не всю структуру в функцию

Tags: c++

Всем привет, с форматированием понимаю косяк, пишу с телефона. Есть структура:

```
struct Test
{
    int a;
    enum Type
    { 
        TEXT = 0, VALUE = 1
    };
};
```

Есть функция:

```
void foo(// передать сюда член структуры Type);
```

Как передать член структуры Type в аргументы функции?

Comment: @ValeraKvip, зачем эти правки?

Comment: А `enum` вполне себе тип, хотя и `int`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, затем что это не моя проблема, что правки вносятся одновременно несколькими пользователями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ideone.com/lvuVHN

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Test
{
    int a;

    enum Type
    { 
        TEXT = 0, VALUE = 1
    };
};

int foo(Test::Type x)
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d\n", foo(Test::TEXT), foo(Test::VALUE));
    return 0;
}
```